# Word for a person who always wanted to get his expected results

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who always wanted to get his expected results?

I'm looking for a trait of a person that means who always wanted to get his expected results.

**For example:** a person ordered a soup and he feels upset when the taste doesn't satisfy him because he is expecting some taste in the soup he ordered.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Could you provide some context in which you'd use the word you're seeking?

Comment: I'm looking for a trait of a person that means who always wanted to get his expected results. For example, a person ordered a soup and he feels upset when the taste doesn't satisfy him because he is expecting some taste in the soup he ordered. @DecapitatedSoul

Comment: Unless we get more context, I would say _dissatisfied_. Your "always" and your example don't work with each other, unless the person is constantly ordering the same soup hoping it will taste different.

Comment: You might want to call him *perfectionist*.

Comment: That person could be a [**stickler**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stickler) – *A person who insists on a certain quality or type of behaviour.*

Comment: ... Souperficial.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That was a rather  _tasteless_ comment...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It's a seafood chowder -- should be "souperfishal"!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.betterhelp.com/advice/personality-disorders/the-psychology-behind-sense-of-entitlement/

**The Psychology Behind Sense Of Entitlement**
By Robert Porter

> ...Then when someone with a sense of entitlement doesn't receive what
>   they expect, they sometimes lash out at others. This doesn't mean that
>   someone who gets angry every so often has a sense of entitlement.
>   However, when someone's disposition consistently changes when they
>   fail to get their way, this is a clear indicator of entitlement.
>
> ...An "entitled" person is someone who falsely believes that they deserve
>   the best and no one else does. Entitled people make unreasonable
>   requests and demands on the world around them on a regular basis.

https://www.coloradomarriageretreats.com/people-act-entitled/

Here are the behaviors of someone who acts entitled:

They are controlling, manipulative or bullying in order to get their way.

They will make demands or ask for sacrifices of others, which are essentially designed to benefit them.

They are extremely impatient.

They get angry easily—and show it.

They will act punishing of people who oppose them or who attempt to interfere with what they want.

They will often be critical of you (and others), because they do not tolerate disappointment well.

Their happiness and well-being comes first.

They take more than they give.

Comment: ...and they shall call her...Karen.